# Semicolon after if condition in PHP - code still works

Tags: php

consider the following code...

```
if ($condition); // <-- do not miss semicolon here!
{
    //...
}
```

After that code inside block works. Can someone explain me why I'm not getting a syntax error?

Comment: because if(...); means if condition do nothing

Comment: It's not normal to have braces floating in the code and it not to be a syntax error. They should be allowed only after some blocks, not anywhere. Totally parsers fault for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to read the manual here:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

To you question directly why: `you don't get a syntax error`?
->Simple because there is no syntax error!

Your code is correct and means this:

```
if ($condition) ;
//  ^condition  ^if true execute that line

//same as
if ($condition)
    ;

//same example with other line if the condition is true
if ($condition) echo "true";

if ($condition)
    echo "true";
```

So your line which gets executed if the condition is true is this: `;` and means nothing.

it's the same as: `;;;;;` It's just nothing!

In most of the time you use a if statement like this:

```
if ($condition)
    echo $result;


if ($condition) {
    echo $result;
}

if ($condition) echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

becuse you can write any code inside `{  }`  without **if**

check this example:

```
<?php

{
    echo 'Hi Man'; // it print Hi Man (without using if statment)
}

?>
```