# Why compare don`t work

Tags: php

How is this possible, what is wrong with all the four checks?
And what is the correct way to check this?

```
<?php
$url = 'domain.dev';
var_dump(strpos($url, 'admin'));

 if(strpos($url, 'admin') ===  false);
 {
    var_dump($url);
 }       

if(strpos($url, 'admin') !== false);
{
   var_dump($url);
}       

if(strpos($url, 'admin') === true);
{
    var_dump($url);
} 

if(strpos($url, 'admin') == true);
{
    var_dump($url);
}
```

The output of this is:

```
bool(false)
string(10) "domain.dev"
string(10) "domain.dev"
string(10) "domain.dev"
string(10) "domain.dev"
```

Comment: Remove the `;` from your ifs.  That terminated the if and then everything after is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Reason explained correctly here:-***[Semicolon after if condition in PHP - code still works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27106395/semicolon-after-if-condition-in-php-code-still-works)

`;` after the `if`will terminate it and next after it everything will going to execute.

So you need to remove `;` at the end of all conditions:-

```
<?php
$url = 'domain.dev';
var_dump(strpos($url, 'admin'));

 if(strpos($url, 'admin') ===  false){
    var_dump($url);
 }       

if(strpos($url, 'admin') !== false){
   var_dump($url);
}       

if(strpos($url, 'admin') === true){
    var_dump($url);
} 

if(strpos($url, 'admin') == true){
    var_dump($url);
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/850447

Comment: Why answer instead of vote to close as typographical error?

Comment: I wasn't talking about the dupe. There is an actual close reason for typographical errors. [See this meta.se post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174389/should-we-answer-or-comment-on-a-typo-question)

Comment: @Ivar  i don't think it's a TYPO mistake at-least. It's a dupe for-sure, but not TYPO

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `;` at the end of the lines with your `if` statements.

e.g:

```
 if(strpos($url, 'admin') ===  false)
 {
    var_dump($url);
 }
```